# Getting Taxonomy Error

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to get taxonomy from post and link. But, link has to be from other custom post "directors" and taxonomy is has to be from other custom post type... I can get taxonomy normally using another code but, i cant get links...

When i trying to use this code i get nothing on page...

What is the problem of this code?

```
<h6 class="box-title"><?php _e( 'Directed by:', 'listingpress' ); ?></h6>
            <div class="director-box-inner">
                <?php

                    $taxonomy ='mydirectors';

                    $term_lists = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);

                    foreach ($term_lists as $termlist):

                    $name_term= $termlist->slug;
                    $argsdirectors = array(
                        'post_type' => 'directors',
                        'name' => $name_term
                        );
                      $loop = new WP_Query($argsdirectors);
                      if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

                        while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();

                ?>


                <div class="agent-card">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="agent-avatar-container">
                        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                         the_post_thumbnail(); 
                        }else{?>
                        <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/profil.png';?>"/>

                            <?php }
                            ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="agent-card-info">
                        <div class="agent-card-info-inner">
                            <h6 class="agent-card-name">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h6>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="button icon-button icon-agent director-profile-buton"><?php _e( 'View Profile', 'listingpress' ); ?></a>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <?php


                endwhile;
                endif;
                endforeach;
                wp_reset_query();
                ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: One thing I noticed real quick is you are missing a ; in href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" it should be <?php the_permalink(); ?> and you are using that in several places

Comment: I did your suggest but not solve my problem :(

Comment: Yea, you have a lot of syntax errors in there. I just noticed another where you start a foreach loop but then don't finish it...

Comment: `foreach ($term_lists as $termlist) {
  $name_term = $termlist->slug;
  $argsdirectors = array(
    'post_type' => 'directors',
    'name' => $name_term
    );
  $loop = new WP_Query($argsdirectors);
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while($loop->have_posts()) {
      $loop->the_post();
    }
  }
}`

Comment: that should be your foreach loop I believe...I suggest looking a little closer at missing semi colons too